# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar los colores por defecto de gráficas superpuestas?

Tags: python, jupyter, color, plot

soy principiante. Estoy graficando varias funciones dentro de dos subfiguras.  Me gustaría cambiar los colores de las curvas desde azul a rojo para representar los cambios en la temperatura, o acceder de alguna manera a la paleta discreta "sns.color_palette("rocket")". He intentado especificando el color dentro de ax1.plot(), pero no funciona. El código es este:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2)= plt.subplots(1,2, sharey = True )
fig.suptitle("f(v) vs v/ṽ ")
ax1.grid()
ax2.grid()

#subfigura 1   (fvh()  y fvn() son funciones definidas anteriormente)

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5= ax1.plot(x,fvh(500,x) , x, fvh(1000,x) , x,fvh(1500,x) ,x,fvh(2000,x) ,x,fvh(2500,x))

#subfigura 2

n1, n2, n3, n4, n5= ax2.plot(x,fvn(500,x) , x,fvn(1000,x) , x,fvn(1500,x) ,x,fvn(2000,x) ,x,fvn(2500,x))

fig.legend(('T= 500 K', 'T= 1000 K', 'T= 1500 K', 'T= 2000 K', 'T= 2500 K'), bbox_to_anchor=(1.12, 0.9))

plt.show()
```

[image: Imagen generada]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes manipular el color pasando el mismo como argumnto en el método .plot(), te un ejemplo simple:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [5, 2, 3]
y1 = [4, 5, 6]

x2 = [1, 3, 5]
y2 = [6, 5, 4]

plt.plot(x1, y1, "g")
plt.plot(x2, y2, "r")
```

Comment: Sí, gracias por tu respuesta. ¿ "color=" también aceptaría un argumento para especificar la tonalidad del color?

Comment: ¿ A qué te refieres con la tonalidad ? Si buscas los colores disponibles para matplotlib seguro encuentras la tonalidad que te interesa.